# What information is contained in a .BMP bitmap image?

Tags: image, bmp, hex-editors

I am trying to read pixels of a `.bmp` bitmap image using hex editor, but this bitmap image has a header file or something. I just need the R,G,B values of every pixel, like what I get in Matlab when I use the `imread` function. How long is the header file of a bitmap or where are the value of pixels located?

Answer (score 1):

`.BMP` file? Wikipedia gives a very good description of header fields: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format

Comment: i don't want to know about header file , i want to know where the pixels values are located, from which address

Comment: And you will find that skipping the header.

Comment: lets say i have a .bmp image how can i know color-index array starts from which byte?

Comment: You read file headers and find out offset of color index (if any), and position of actual data. This is the file format: headers + data; one of the headers might embed a palette. Wiki gives you the structure (check pictures there).

Answer (score 0):

Also see [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=bitmap%20file%20format&ac=3). From that you can find [About Bitmaps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162461%28VS.85%29.aspx).